# If $a_n < b_n$ for all $n$, then $\lim a_n \leq \lim b_n$

Tags: limits, inequality

> If $a_n < b_n$ for all $n$, then $\lim a_n \leq \lim b_n$.

I'm not sure how to prove this. In particular, why is there "$\leq$" in the limits?

Comment: If $a_n < b_n \; \forall \; n$, then it follows that $b_n - a_n > 0 \; \forall \; n$

Comment: For your second question, consider $a_n = -1/n$ and $b_n = 1/n$. Term-by-term, the inequality is strict, but the sequences have the same limit.

Comment: Simply because $c_n=b_n-a_n$ can approach a limit without ever being equal to it - and $c_n$ can have properties like being positive and decreasing and still tend to a limit.

Comment: You need to assume that both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent.

Comment: See also [Suppose that $(s_n)$ converges to $s$, $(t_n)$ converges to $t$, and $s_n \leq t_n \: \forall \: n$. Prove that $s \leq t$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1850471) and other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1850471).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a_n < b_n$ then $c_n=b_n-a_n>0$ for all $n$, therefore 
$$\lim c_n\geq0$$
otherwise let $\lim c_n=\ell<0$, there exists $N$ such that for $n\geq N$
$$|c_n-\ell|<\ell/2$$
and $c_N<\frac32\ell<0$ contradict with $c_n>0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

To give a proof of this I would personally go for a contradiction:

Assume that $\lim a_n > \lim b_n$, let $\epsilon = \lim a_n - \lim b_n$ ans consider a $N$ such that $|a_N-\lim a_n|<\epsilon/3$ and $|b_N-\lim b_n|<\epsilon/3$ (it exists because of the definition of the limit). Then find a contradiction with $a_N<b_N$.

As for the equality The example given in the comment by Blue is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n < b_n$ then the largest value of $a_n$ is smaller than the smallest value of $b_n$. But since these sequences are infinite, we express this in terms of $\sup$ and $\inf$, namely:

$$\sup \{a_n \} \leq \inf \{ b_n \}$$

and hence it follows that for the limit superior and limit inferior we have

$$\limsup \{a_n\} \leq \liminf \{b_n\}$$

Since $\lim \{x_n\}$ is defined as being the $x$ such that $\liminf \{x_n\} = \limsup \{x_n\} = x$ the result follows.

If this is confusing to you, I'd recommend reading the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior).

To answer your second question why an equality is necessary, consider what happens if $b_n$ converges to $x$ from above, while $a_n$ converges to $x$ from below.