# Hausdorff Dimension of an Intersection

Tags: measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

Let $E$ and $F$ be two non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

*I'm wondering if there's a simple formula or bound for the Hausdorff dimension of $E \cap F$ in terms of the Hausdorff dimension of $E$ and the Hausdorff dimension of $F$.*

My instinct tells me that we could write
$$\dim_H E \cap F \leq \min (\dim_H E,\ \dim_H F)$$
but this only comes from my (probably naive) intuition. For example, taking a line which intersects a plane, the Hausdorff dimension of the intersection can only be 0 (intersects at a point) or 1 (line is contained in the plane), both of which are less than or equal to 1, the Hausdorff dimension of the line. Clearly their intersection cannot be any more than 1 dimension, and I think this sort of reasoning can apply to general sets $E$ and $F$.

*Does this actually hold for general subsets $E, F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and if so, how would I make the above argument rigorous?*

Comment: You only need to show, that $X\subseteq Y$ implies $\dim_HX\leq\dim_HY$. Your result then follows when applying this to the inclusions $E\cap F\subseteq E$ and $E\cap F\subseteq F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the following with the [formal definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#Formal_definition) (also linked on its [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hausdorff+dimension)): Let $X\subseteq Y$ be subsets of a metric space. Every countable open cover $(U_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $Y$ with $\operatorname{diam}(U_i)<\delta$ for every $i\in I$ is also a countable open cover of $X$, hence $H_\delta^d(X)\leq H_\delta^d(Y)$. Since [limits preserve (weak) inequalities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850471), we have $H^d(X)\leq H^d(Y)$. Since outer measures are always positive, we have $H^d(Y)=0\Rightarrow H^d(X)=0$ or $\{d\geq 0|H^d(Y)=0\}\subseteq\{d\geq 0|H^d(X)=0\}$. Applying the infimum [yields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Properties) $\dim_H(X)\leq\dim_H(Y)$. According to my comment above, this yields your formula, when being applied to the inclusions $E\cap F\subseteq E$ and $E\cap F\subseteq F$.