# Trying to prove a relationship as $N_b \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Given that:

$$W_b = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N_b} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{M_i} W_{i,j}}{M_i}}{N_b}$$

and

$$W = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N_b} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{M_i} W_{i,j}\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^{N_b} M_i}$$

and it is known for a fact that $W_b \leq W$ for finite $N_b$, how do you
prove, as $N_b \rightarrow \infty$ that the relation

$$W_b \leq W$$

is true?

I'm really struggling to get started with this one. It just seems to me that since
this relation is true for every finite number, why would it not be true for $\infty$?

$\bf{Is\ this\ a\ possible\ proof?}$

The statement $W_b \leq W$ has already been proved for all possible values of $N_b$, including $N_b \rightarrow \infty$. The analysis does not depend on the value of $N_b$, but rather on the relationships within each term of the expressions. That is,

1. The denominator of $W_b$ ($N_b$) is always less than or equal to the denominator of $W$ ($\sum_{i=1}^{N_b} M_i$) because each busy period ($N_b$) has at least one customer ($M_i$).
2. The numerator of $W_b$ is the sum of the averages of waiting times during each busy period. We calculate the average waiting time for each busy period by dividing the sum of waiting times for that period ($\sum_{j=1}^{M_i} W_{i,j}$) by the number of customers served during that period ($M_i$).
3. The numerator of $W$ is the sum of all waiting times during each busy period.

Given these facts, each term in the numerator of $W_b$ is less than or equal to the corresponding term in the numerator of $W$, and the denominator of $W_b$ is less than or equal to the denominator of $W$. Therefore, $W_b \leq W$.

The limit of $N_b \rightarrow \infty$ does not change this relationship. As $N_b$ increases, both $W$ and $W_b$ tend to be more accurate representations of the average waiting time in the system and during a busy period, respectively. However, the relationship $W_b \leq W$ still holds. In other words, the average waiting time during a busy period will always be less than or equal to the average waiting time in the system as a whole.

Comment: Do you know $W$ and $W_b$ converge for $N_b\to\infty$?

Comment: Yes they can and do if certain criteria are met - but in this case they do

Comment: Ok, so you have two sequences, $W$ and $W_b$, and want to know if (why) their limits preserve $\le$. You can find multiple possible answers here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1850471/293177

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose that $(s_n)$ converges to $s$, $(t_n)$ converges to $t$, and $s_n \leq t_n \: \forall \: n$. Prove that $s \leq t$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1850471/suppose-that-s-n-converges-to-s-t-n-converges-to-t-and-s-n-leq-t)

Comment: Let me think about this...

Comment: Any progress? I see my duplicate flag has been declined, even though it seems you were asking precisely about it.